# What is the Fastest way of looping over an array on javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to do loops in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193547/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-loops-in-javascript)
>   [What’s the best way to loop through a set of elements in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157260/whats-the-best-way-to-loop-through-a-set-of-elements-in-javascript)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check this [JavaScript loop benchmarks](http://www.devpro.it/examples/loopsbench/).

Comment: @Plan B: Yeah, look this article also: http://www.moddular.org/log/javascript-loops/

Comment: Hopefully this encourages you to go with whatever is clearest--not fastest. They're all fast.

Comment: @Micheal - Yeah in my Opera the first without any optimization is often the fastest...

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with a good old-fashioned `for` loop?

```
for( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
    // do something with list[i]
}
```

The semantics of `for...in` and `for...each...in` tend to confuse people and lead to unexpected results.

Comment: In Javascript variable resolution is late bound. In your example above you would need to resolve length every iteration of the loop. You should cache the length variable by doing for (var i=0, l=list.length;i<l;i++). Good rule of thumb is the less dots the better in JS.

Answer (score 0):

CMS's link should show you for small data sets they're all fast, the only thing i'd suggest is that you avoid `for (a in b)` as it has a much higher memory overhead than any other looping construct and can potentially be much slower due to its "interesting" semantics.

Anyhoo, with the exception of `for(in)` any real JS should be spending quite a bit more time actually doing real work than is spent handling the looping itself, so minor variation in cost of the loop shouldn't be too important.

Answer (score 0):

This was covered recently in [Greg Reimer's Weblog](http://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a).

The quick answer is this:

```
for (var i=0, node; node = hColl[i++];) {
    // do something with node
}
```

Comment: why the `i++` there? you will need to use `(i-1)` to "do something with node"

Answer (score 0):

As answered elsewhere (why does this thread exist?): the reverse while:

```
var i = foo.length; while (i--) { /* do something with foo[i] */ }
```

..is the fastest loop if you can deal with the caveats that:

- reverse order isn't always suitable
- it's a bit hard to read
- it adds a variable to the footprint of whatever scope it's in
- it's only slightly faster than the smaller footprinted and more readable cached length `for` loop

Comment: If the array is 0 based then you should use --i in the while loop otherwise it will be out of bounds
var i = foo.length; while (--i) { /* do something with foo[i] */ }

Comment: You can see here that this is not always true: http://jsperf.com/loops/33. Most loops caching the array's length are more or less equally fast.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly objects are faster... For example:

```
var array = {"0": "foo", "1": "bar"}
for(var i in array){
    var val = array[i];
    // do something
}
```