# i want to replace that html code with javascript code?

Tags: php, javascript, html

i want to replace all between `<p>` tags with a simple word `NotFound`

```
<p id='2'>
        <?php
        foreach ($d as $key=>$value) 
        {
                    extract($value);
                            if($key%4==0)
                            {
                                  echo "</tr>";
                                  echo"<tr>";
                            }
                    include('item.php');
        }
        echo"</table>";
        echo"</div>";

   ?>
 </p>
```

how can i do that using javaScript??

**update:**
i used that code in the javascript area:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=msg;
        function msg(){
            document.getElementById('1').onclick=clickhandlee;

            //
        }
        function clickhandlee(){
            var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
        for(var i=0, max=ps.length; i<max; i++){
        ps[i].innerHTML = "NotFound";
      }

        }



        </script>
```

and the same previous code in the `<body>` tags

```
<p id='2'>
        <?php
        foreach ($d as $key=>$value) 
        {
                    extract($value);
                            if($key%4==0)
                            {
                                  echo "</tr>";
                                  echo"<tr>";
                            }
                    include('item.php');
          }
        echo"</table>";
        echo"</div>";

   ?>
 </p>
```

this is the included php template `item.php`

```
<td style='border: 0px none ; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 240px;' align='right' valign='top'>
           <div style='margin-bottom: 10px;'>
    <table class='topic' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='right'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style='background: url(&#039;style/$style/images/top_background.jpg&#039;) no-repeat left center; -moz-background-clip: border; -moz-background-origin: padding; -moz-background-inline-policy: continuous' align='center' height='35'>
                <div style='overflow: hidden; width: 230px;'>
                <a class='link' href='t<?=$id;?>-<?=$name;?>.html'>
                    <?=$name;?> </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center' style="height: 197px">
                <a href='count-<?=$id;?>;.html'>
            <img src='<?=$photo;?>' class='image' border='0' width='220' height='170'/></a>
                <div dir='rtl' class='shortdes'><?=$shortdes;?></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign='top'>
            <td style='background: url(&#039;style/$style/images/footer_background.jpg&#039;) no-repeat left center; -moz-background-clip: border; -moz-background-origin: padding; -moz-background-inline-policy: continuous; height: 29px;' align='center' height='35'>
            <a class='dlink' href='count-<?=$id;?>.html'>
                <div class='download' style="height: 17px">

                      التحميل : <?=$visits;?>
                    </div></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: `i want to replace that html code with javascript code??`.
No you don't, sorry.

Comment: Could you post the actual markup generated, rather than the PHP template?

Comment: The HTML here seems to cause the browser to implicitly close the `<p>` tag immediately after open rather than wrapping the rest of the markup (see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/muvnQ/) example), at least in Firefox inspected with Firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using Javascript

*Note comment by user DA - IDs cannot start with a number before HTML 5, so assume that the ID is spelled out (two) instead of the numeral (2) if not using HTML 5.*

If it is only for the `<p>` tag with id=two:

```
document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = "NotFound";
```

If it is for all `<p>` tags:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    paragraphs[i].innerHTML = "NotFound";
}
```

The key is the innerHTML tag of the DOM elements.

Comment: @justkt : it add the `NotFound` string above the existing not replacing it

Comment: @Buffon - please update your question to show where and how you are calling this code.  `innerHTML` when applied correctly should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Heads up: IDs can not start with a number.

Comment: @DA: IDs can start with a number in HTML5.

Comment: @Buffon - that is because your HTML doesn't appear to be liked by the browser.  When I tried in jsfiddle (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/muvnQ/)) I reproduced your problem.  I inspected it with firebug and the browser is implicitly closing the `<p>` tag right after it is created.  Try running your HTML through a validator and cleaning it up.  Basically what is happening is that `<p>` does not wrap your contents.

Comment: @justkt : thank u for trying but what i should do as this code was working fine before i want to add some javascript codes

Comment: @Buffon - it might appear to work, but it is *not* working.  It's not valid.  Run your HTML through [the validator](http://validator.w3.org/), clean up errors in the HTML, then try again.

Comment: @justkt : the vaidator gives me errors which i can't remove it like it gives me an error of using `php` tags i can't remove it or i wont fetch any information from database.. i tried that validator with `http://google.com/` and it also give errors how could that believe anymore??

Comment: @Buffon - run your *output* by the validator - the generated HTML,   not the PHP.

Comment: @justkt : i do that thank u but using the id to that `table` markup itself not `p` thank u very much for trying help

Answer (score 2):

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
    i = paragraphs.length;

while (i--)
{
    paragraphs[i].innerHTML = 'NotFound';
}
```

Comment: @Matt Ball : it add the `NotFound` string above the existing not replacing it

Comment: It added the `NotFound` string above the existing ______?

Comment: I was taught to use for loops when you know the number of loops and a while when you don't. Was I taught wrong?

Comment: @Ash: it's just a [minor optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421794/what-is-the-fastest-way-of-looping-over-an-array-on-javascript) that I like to use. It takes a little less characters to write, and a little less time to execute.

Comment: How does it know when to stop. Is -1 evaluated to false?

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript:

```
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(var i=0, max=ps.length; i<max; i++)
    ps[i].innerHTML = "NotFound";
```

Comment: This is identical to the solution that I already posted, but less efficient.

Comment: it add the `NotFound` string above the existing not replacing it

Comment: For your future reference you don't need to use max. Simply for(var i=0; i<ps.Length; i++).

Comment: @Ash: it is faster to store the length separately, otherwise it's evaluated at every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery: `$('p').html('NotFound');`