# which of the given for loop is faster?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, operator-precedence

Well,I went for interview today and there Interviewer asked me a question and it's like this.

```
    let a = "Aditya";
    1.for (let i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    2.for(let i=a.length; i>0; i--)
    3.for(let i=0, length=a.length; i<length; i++)
```

which of the above for loop runs faster 1 , 2 , 3?
Arrange it, and give the reason as well.
I was like well I used (1) most the so it could be the faster one but he told me I was wrong and I tried google couldn't find any helpful solution.Please help me out.

Comment: For almost all applications it absolutely does not matter. Worry about algorithmic efficiency and not pointless minutia like this. (And that should have been the answer to the interview question.)

Comment: If `a.length` is non-negative then 2 is definitely faster...

Comment: Why can't you do some tests yourself? https://jsperf.com/

Comment: @David lol I just noticed that

Comment: @David Can you please explain why it is?

Comment: One thing to remember is that in 1 - `a.length` is checked each time.

Comment: @adityashrivastwa: Because loops which never execute are faster than loops which do execute.

Comment: "He" wanted you to answer "3" because 3 caches `a.length` so that it doesn't have to be calculated upon each loop iteration.

Comment: @David Sorry,It was my fault I didn't write the code properly.It's edited now and I think may be the Interviewer wants to trick me?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yeah he told me 3rd one is the fastest and 2nd is equivalent to it and the 1st one is sowest.

Comment: @ScottMarcus "so that it doesn't have to be calculated upon each loop iteration" [Not really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112361/is-javascript-str-length-calculated-every-time-it-is-called-or-just-once).

Comment: @adityashrivastwa The question you got asked is useless and the "correct" answer you got is, depending on the implementation, even wrong.

Comment: @str You're comment is based on the optimizations of one client and not the language in general. And, while I think we all agree that this is really not a question with any practical benefit, we can all understand that the question was asked to see if the interviewee can spot and understand such optimization opportunities.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Discussing performance on a theoretical level is even more useless then microoptimization. If optimization opportunities is what the question is about, then the interviewer did not get that either. There is no universally correct answer to the question.

Comment: @str You miss my point. I'm fairly confident the question was asked to solicit the exact kind of conversation that we are having in this thread. If the answer is "I don't know", then that is telling about the level of experience the interviewee has. If the answer is "Always 3", that's telling as well. If the answer is, "It really isn't a discernible difference, then that can spawn a conversation about why. No matter what answer is given, the interviewer will gain an understanding of the level of knowledge of the interviewee.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I did get your point, that is why I wrote "the interviewer did not get that either" as they claimed the third answer is the "correct" one :) I fully agree with your last comment but your first one seemed too absolute and might be wrong in some implentations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best answer is probably:

Why do you even care? Choose the one that is the most readable. Unreadable code takes more time for people to understand, and the benefits of a few milliseconds faster do not matter. If such small performance things matter, you should be writing assembly.

> He told me 3rd one is the fastest and 2nd is equivalent to it and the 1st one is slowest.

Not really. Modern browsers do optimize all three loops so much that they actually run with the same speed.

Comment: "the second and third are [...] faster". [Or it might be the opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112361/is-javascript-str-length-calculated-every-time-it-is-called-or-just-once).

Comment: @str that tests an entire different thing. But yes, this is premature optimization.

Comment: The JSPerf example is about repetitive access of the string length which is exactly what you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @str 1) testing with only 10 accesses makes no sense at all as most JIT engines will only inline after a certain number of calls 2) testing with code that does not do anything makes no sense either as the engine might actually does not exexcute it. 3) only accessing a length does not mean iterating. Other optimizations apply here 4) as it looks like inside the loop `str[i]` is probably accessed which needs to be taken into consideration too. => The testcase you linked doesnt say anything, and nothing concerning the question. My testcase isnt perfect either but probably a better estimation.

Comment: @str okay, i revoke the testcase. By swapping the examples (running one before the other) it also swapped the timed results, so it seems like the difference was just some server warmup time.

Comment: Those performance tests are always approximations and only real life measurements are actually useful. Thanks for the update on your answer, I think now it is a good response the the question (even though the question is sketchy).