# For jQuery purist - simple array filling?

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

- [What is the best way to do loops in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193547/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-loops-in-javascript)

  - http://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a
  - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/
  - http://api.jquery.com/each/

I still for my own education want to see an elegant jQuery version of a construct like this - Note the image filenames are 1 based and not 0 based :

```
var nofImages = 10; // user defined
var slideShowArray = new Array(nofImages); // cannot use [nofImages] of course
for (var i=0, n=slideShowArray.length;i<n;i++) {
  slideShowArray[i]="/images/image"+(i+1)+".jpg";
}
```

or perhaps according to the above mentioned articles it should be

```
var nofImages = 10; // user defined
var slideShowArray = [];
for (i=nofImages;i>0;i--) {
  slideShowArray[(i-1)]="/images/image"+i+".jpg";
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var slideShowArray = $.map(new Array(10), function(i,j) {
    return '/images/image'+(j+1)+'.jpg';
});
```

In Javascript 1.8 you will be able to do this more elegantly:

```
var slideShowArray = $.map(new Array(10), function(i,j) '/images/image'+(j+1)+'.jpg');
```

or even

```
$.range = function(first,last,step) {
    step = step || 1;
    if (typeof last == undefined) {
        last = first;
        first = 0;
    }
    return $.map(Array((first-last)/step), function(i,j) {
        return j*step + first;
    });
}

var slideShowArray = ['/images/image'+i+'.jpg' for (i in $.range(1,10))];
```

Comment: That is more what I was looking for. In your example the "i" is not interesting since it is just a necessary placeholder for the empty initialised array element, right?

Comment: Indeed, first parameter is array element, second is array index. You could write `function(_,i) {...+(i+1)+...}` if you like that sort of stuff.

Comment: Great. Not sure I like the 1.8 versions at all.. I want my curly brackets ;)

Answer (score 2):

Trying to be a jquery purist you might want to try the [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method.

```
var noOfImages = 10;
var slideShowArray = [];
slideShowArray[noOfImages - 1] = ""; // set initial size
slideShowArray = $.map(slideShowArray, function(element, index) {
  return "/images/image"+index+".jpg"
});
```

But I think this would be simpler:

```
var noOfImages = 10;
var slideShowArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < noOfImages; i++) 
  slideShowArray.push("/images/image"+i+".jpg");
```

(Note that your examples are a bit broken - setting the array to `[noOfImages]` sets the length to 1.)

Comment: Sorry. Mixed my initialiser from new Array(nofImages) and []. However your second example is another non-jquery example. It is broken too ;) It does not use 1 based image names. I wanted to find a plausible jQuery each-type script to see if it was too horrible to use or not ;)

Comment: "Initializing" the array by setting the last element is not safe - the current behavior of map might be to walk from 1 to the last index, and not skip unset indexes, but there is no promise in the jQuery API to behave that way.

Comment: @mplugjan: nope, your image names are broken ;)

Comment: Haha, Not mine. I always use 0 based names or SEO best practise names